# Building a C# cache with byte[] key, and eviction policy

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wanting to build a cache with an eviction policy in C#.  My key is a byte array (fixed at 32 bytes) and value is an instance of a specific class.

I'm debating the best way to do this.  I'm thinking that `MemoryCache` is the way to go, but it uses `string` for a key.  I could turn this into a hex-string but that incurs some overhead.  Why isn't the key an arbitrary object like in a dictionary?

It's trivial to write a byte array comparer and there's a suitable `Dictionary` constructor to supply an `IEqualityComparer`, but this approach doesn't give me an eviction strategy for free.

Are there any other options I'm overlooking?

Comment: Meh, use Convert.ToBase64String and move on with your life.

Comment: I had the same issue, in my case it was slightly worse because i wanted a truly generic MemoryCache that would be able to have any type of Key.
In my case created a class that used MemoryCache but it had to also provide key conversion methods.
Never was as nice as i wanted, but i didn't want to have to try to replicate some of the complex stuff the MemoryCache was doing under the hood.

In a new application that i have done we just implemented timed caching using a Dictionary and overrode the Get and Set methods. That way you can use anything for a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MemoryCache` is actually fairly complex under the hood (grab a copy of Reflector and take a look if you haven't already). There are several things it does which are non-trivial to replicate; chief among these is approximating memory size used by cached objects.

Performance-wise, you will be contending with **much** more significant impacts than the massaging of a key. Performance is acceptable, but key management is an insignificant part of the process.

You can see this difference by performing 100K+ add operations on a `Dictionary` versus `MemoryCache`.

Here's a little hex algorithm you can use on your byte keys which I have tweaked to be as fast as possible. The BCL also contains base 16 functionality (which I didn't know when I wrote this code and I've kept it around because it is simpler/faster).

*As noted in the comments, converting the `byte[]` to hex is probably not even needed to meet the stated requirements unless the key will be used elsewhere.*

```
public unsafe sealed class Hex
{
    private static readonly char[] _hexRange = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a byte array into a string of base-16 values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>Base-16 encoded string.</returns>
    public static string ToHexString( byte[] value )
    {
        char* buffer = stackalloc char[( value.Length * 2 ) + 1]; // +1 for null terminator
        char* start = buffer;

        for( int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++ )
        {
            *buffer++ = _hexRange[value[i] / 16];
            *buffer++ = _hexRange[value[i] % 16];
        }

        return new string( start );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're doing unsafe code anyway, why convert to hex at all? Pin `value`, cast the pointer to `char*` and construct a string using the `String(char* value, int startIndex, int length)` constructor.

Comment: I use hex to generate safe/consistent values (for purposes like URLs) but your suggestion probably makes more sense for the OP. The key used for MemoryCache can be any string.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one solution would be to look for a library on the web. Like an LRU-list.

On the other hand, MemoryCache is well-tested and well-designed. It is likely to be pretty fast. If the performance overhead of calculating the string-keys is acceptable I'd just go with that solution. My guess would be that calculating the key is far less overhead than doing the cache operation, but that is a guess (need to measure).

Comment: I think I might be overestimating the penalty of the string key calculation.  I'll wait a while to see if anyone else chirps in but I like your answer